# create a new csv file in new subdirectory python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, csv, os.path

Been having trouble with using variables in a new dirpath when using `with open` to create a csv file.
I can create the dirpath fine along with the .csv filename and add them with os.path.join .
But when i try to use the entire correctly formatted path in the open statement it is adding an extra backslash next to the current backslashes in the string?? could not find any documentation on why this may be happening.

This is the error

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Logs\\14-05-2018\\dfg.csv'`

If i simply write the following i can create the subfolders and csvs no problemo.

`with open(Logs\1234\asd.csv) 'w') as csvfile:`

So this is what i am getting an error in on line 43 which is the `with open(csvlogPath, 'w') as csvfile:` I have tried with `r` instead of 'w' and same problem. At a loss after two days time to ask you guys. :)

```
import csv, os.path

#Get and create csv filename string
logFN = input("Please name your trade.\n#")            
suffix = '.csv'
csvname = logFN + suffix
#Create dir name string
t = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H%M")
dirsname = os.path.join('Logs', t)

csvlogPath = os.path.join(dirsname,csvname)

with open(csvlogPath, 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    filewriter.writerow(['get', 'new', 'values', 'later'])

with open(csvlogPath, 'w') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
 # read file row by row
    rwsCount = 0    
    for row in reader:        
        print (row, rwsCount)
        rwsCount += 1

line_number = rwsCount-1
print (line_number)

with open(csvlogPath, 'w') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    text = mycsv[line_number][0]

print (text)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the dirs in python you can use `os.makedirs(path)` like so:

```
csvlogPath = os.path.join(dirsname,csvname)
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(csvlogPath), exist_ok=True)
with open(csvlogPath, 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    filewriter.writerow(['get', 'new', 'values', 'later'])
```

With open, use 'r' to read and 'w' to write so you need to change the next to opens to:

```
with open(csvlogPath, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
 # read file row by row
    rwsCount = 0    
    for row in reader:        
        print (row, rwsCount)
        rwsCount += 1

line_number = rwsCount-1
print (line_number)

with open(csvlogPath, 'r') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    text = mycsv[line_number][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

test this code :

```
import csv, os.path

#Get and create csv filename string
import time

logFN = input("Please name your trade.\n#")
suffix = '.csv'
csvname = logFN + suffix
#Create dir name string
t = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H%M")
dirsname = os.path.join('Logs', t)

###########################
if not os.path.exists(dirsname):
    os.makedirs(dirsname)
###########################


csvlogPath = os.path.join(dirsname,csvname)

with open(csvlogPath, 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    filewriter.writerow(['get', 'new', 'values', 'later'])

with open(csvlogPath, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
 # read file row by row
    rwsCount = 0
    for row in reader:
        print (row, rwsCount)
        rwsCount += 1

line_number = rwsCount-1
print (line_number)

with open(csvlogPath, 'r') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    text = mycsv[line_number][0]

print (text)
```

Comment: also perfect!! but has the checking if already created so a bit better, i did actually try a version of this but failed earlier